# Select top n (variable) for each criteria in a table based on another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I want a VBA code to make a query to show Equip with Top ActiveTime for each ModelID (from 1st table) based on TopN for each ModelID (from the 2nd table), I know i have to use QueryDef and Sql VBA but I can't figure how to write the code

Just and Example to illustrate

My 1st table is

| EquipID | Equip | ActimeTime | ModelID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DT1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | DT2 | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | DT3 | 13 | 1 |
| 4 | DT4 | 15 | 1 |
| 5 | DT5 | 16 | 2 |
| 6 | DT6 | 12 | 2 |
| 7 | DT7 | 6 | 2 |
| 8 | DT8 | 13 | 2 |

My 2nd Table is

| ModelID | Model | TopN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 775 | 3 |
| 2 | 789 | 2 |

So the query result should be like (Showing the Top **3** of 775 Model and the Top **2** of 789)

| Equip | ActimeTime | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DT4 | 15 | 775 |
| DT3 | 13 | 775 |
| DT1 | 10 | 775 |
| DT5 | 16 | 789 |
| DT8 | 13 | 789 |

Thanks a lot in advance, I'm really stuck at this one and solving this will help me a lot in my project

[Table1][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/geMca.png
[Table2][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPDP.png
[Query Result][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGf6k.png

Comment: You don't need VBA to make a query - write the query first then show us the SQL and the problem you encounter if any

Comment: You _do_ need VBA to create the query. While `Model` can be retrieved and filtered on, the `TOP n` clause cannot be dynamic. Thus, use VBA to modify queries to hold - in this case - either `TOP 2` or `TOP 3`.

Comment: @dbmitch I tried to write the query in SQL but TOP argument don't accept a variable it have to be a number (i.e. Select TOP 5 ActiveTime), maybe you can help me with an example to how to do it in SQL

Comment: @Gustav The above tables were just an example, unfortunately the Model table has much more entries and we need to show for each Model the Top Equip achieved Active time based on the adjacent Top N

Comment: OK, go ahead. Have in mind please, that SO is not a code writing service but a code _helper_ forum.

Comment: @Gustav I was able to do it with just SQL but I guess Dcount is technically VBA. Half right?

Comment: Yes. If you like, `DCount` can be replaced with a subquery finding the count. It may be a bit faster but not slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in straight SQL - but oooh is it ugly to follow and construct

I created 4 queries with the final one resulting in what you're looking for.

The key was to get a RowID based on the sorted order you're looking for (Model and ActimeTime). You can get a pseudo Row ID using `Dcount`

Here's the 4 queries - I'm sure you can make one mashup if you're daring

My tables are `Table3` and `Table4` - you can change them in the first query to match your database. ***Build these queries in order as they are dependent on the one before them***

**qListModels**

```
SELECT Table3.Equip, Table3.ActimeTime, Table4.Model, Table4.TopN, "" & [Model] & "-" & Format([ActimeTime],"000") AS [Model-ActTime]
FROM Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.ModelID = Table4.ModelID
ORDER BY Table4.Model, Table3.ActimeTime DESC;
```

**qListModelsInOrder**

```
SELECT qListModels.*, DCount("[Model-ActTime]","[qListModels]","[Model-ActTime]>=" & """" & [Model-ActTime] & """") AS row_id
FROM qListModels;
```

**qListModelStartRows**

```
SELECT qListModelsInOrder.Model, Min(qListModelsInOrder.row_id) AS MinOfrow_id
FROM qListModelsInOrder
GROUP BY qListModelsInOrder.Model;
```

**qListTopNModels**

```
SELECT qListModelsInOrder.Equip, qListModelsInOrder.ActimeTime, qListModelsInOrder.Model
FROM qListModelsInOrder INNER JOIN qListModelStartRows ON qListModelsInOrder.Model = qListModelStartRows.Model
WHERE ((([row_id]-[MinOfrow_id])<[TopN]))
ORDER BY qListModelsInOrder.Model, qListModelsInOrder.ActimeTime DESC;
```

This last one can be run anytime to get the results you want

**Example Output:**

[image: Results of Top N Model Query]

Comment: Very neat. If you have many records, and the RowId appears to be the bottleneck, you might take advantage of my `RowNumber` function found at _GitHub_: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

Comment: @ dbmitch Just brilliant smart solution, I totally believed that it can be done only by VBA, thanks a lot mate, not just for the help but also I really learnt a lot from your solution

Comment: @Gustav Thanks mate for your time and guidance, The RowNumber function looks very interesting too

Comment: @MMN thanks - glad it helped. If you consider it a solution, please mark it as the answer with that checkmark - it's our little reward for helping.